# Tobit Regression Chi-Square

Tags: python, regression

First off, I'm replicating a Tobit Regression table that includes Chi-Square and Pr > Chi-Square aside from the coef estimates.

I'm familiar with the general concept for Tobit and Chi-Square testing but I'm not familiar enough with it to be able to reproduce it mathematically. Specifically, I'm trying to figure out how to recover Chi-Square for this in Python.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/jamesdj/tobit/) package. It's clear how to recover the coefs and I thought the `.sigma_` attribute would be what I'm looking for but it's scalar and not a vector so I'd be surprised if it was related to the standard errors for the coefs.

If I could get some steering in the right direction that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this code, to get the coefficient of determination, which is a good indicator for what you need:

```
import numpy as np
x = <your set of dependent variables>
y = <your independent variable>
cens = <the cens vector as defined in the library documentation>

tobit  = TobitModel()
rTobit = tobit.fit(x, y, cens, verbose=False)
yHat   = rTobit.predict(x)
yHat   = yHat.reshape(yHat.shape[0],1)

yMean = np.full((yHat.shape[0],1), y.mean()[0])

cDet  = np.dot(np.transpose(yHat-yMean), yHat-yMean) / np.dot(np.transpose(y-yMean), y-yMean)
```

Tobit regression is very useful in cases when you are estimating variables like percentage of availability, which range between 0 and 100.

Comment: Nice! I ended up using R for what I needed... I wrote a script and called it from python and then imported the results back in the Python so that all analytics could be centralized. I'll definitely look more at this next time I'm running Tobit. Thank you!